# Is ImageIO.read(file) vulnerable to attack?

Tags: java, security, servlets

A user is allowed to upload only image files to a servlet. After I temporarily store on the server, I read the file to make sure it is an image and maybe do some extra manipulations eg:

```
  try {
           InputStream input = uploadedFile.getInputStream()
       if (ImageIO.read(input)!=null)
          { 
                doStuff();
          } else { // Not an image }
      } catch (Exception e)
      {

      }
```

Is this vulnerable to any attacks? Or is this considered safe?

Comment: I'd search for something like "ImageIO security vulnerabilities".